# Adding a query to GoToAsync URI Navigation in Xamarin Forms Shell causes it to stop working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, xamarin.shell

So for this issue I have a pretty simple stack. Main Menu Screen > List Page > Detail Page. For each page I am getting to it using

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync({name of page});
```

so basically a push and then going back in the stack with

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../");
```

This is all working fine until I introduced queries to pass data.

So this works fine

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Page)}");
```

But this

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Page)}?Id={some id here}");
```

Throws this exception

```
Relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported. 
Try prefixing your uri with ///: ///PageName?Id=3AC71D0B-D8E3-6C18-FFE3-6D41E154F000
```

Which makes no sense because the navigation clearly works without the query included. Where am I going wrong? Is this bug or is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported.
> Try prefixing your uri with ///: ///PageName?Id=3AC71D0B-D8E3-6C18-FFE3-6D41E154F000

That means you are using [Relative routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#relative-routes) , however this not supports for passing data before Xamarin Forms `4.7`.

If using the version of Xamarin Forms before `4.7` .you need to use [Absolute routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#absolute-routes) to pass data , example as follow :

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//animals/elephants/elephantdetails?name={elephantName}");
```

And to receive data, the class that represents the page being navigated to, or the class for the page's `BindingContext`, must be decorated with a QueryPropertyAttribute for each query parameter:

```
[QueryProperty("Name", "name")]
public partial class ElephantDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            BindingContext = ElephantData.Elephants.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == Uri.UnescapeDataString(value));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

More info can refer here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

=============================Update===============================

As Shane's said , from the version of Xamarin Forms above `4.7`, **Relative routes** also supports passing paramaters now .

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for this information, it was exactly what I needed. I have put in a pull request to add this information to the documentation.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/pull/2952

Comment: I have also raised an enhancement request for a more descriptive exception when this happens. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11220

Comment: @Sev Thanks for putting in a pull request ,and I will also check this issue . If there are good news , github will mark you :-)

Comment: @Sev this is not intended behavior. Passing data with relative routes should work fine. I think this might be a bug that was fixed in the latest 4.7 release. I've attached notes here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11220

Comment: @ShaneNeuville Thanks for reminder , answer has been updated. :-)

Comment: Sorry to resuscitate this, but I'm using 5.0 and seem to have the same problem. Is this a regression or a different problem?

Comment: I implement the above solution but using a view model which's the page's binding context. However, the view model receives null objects when it is decorated with a QueryProperty attribute and even when implementing IQueryAttributable with the ApplyQueryAttributes method. I can ensure that the passed data is a real-working object before it is passed, but it is null when receiving. Also, when I foreach loop for the query dictionary, I find the relavant key(s) but with null value(s). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and solved it by registering the page into the `AppShell.xaml.cs`

```cs
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MyPage),
                typeof(MyPage));
```